# dropdown menu using for loop not retaining value in dropdown

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, laravel-4

Hi i am developing an application using laravel 4, i have a drop down menu which generate values using for each loop the problem here is once if i select a value and save the form the value gets saved in database but when i try to edit the same it's getting retained to the default value so my question is how to retain previously selected the drop down value?

Here is my code please take a look

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('last_closing_financial_year') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label class="control-label" for="last_closing_financial_year">Enter the Last Closing Financial Year</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php
                $years = array();
                for ($i = 1980; $i < 2050; $i++)
                {                       
                  $years[] = $i;
                } 
                echo '<select name="last_closing_financial_year" class="controls assettext select2 selectyear" id="last_closing_financial_year" >';
                echo '<option value="">-- Select Year --</option>';
                foreach($years as $option)
                {
                    echo "<option value='{$option}'";
                    $optionprev= $option+1;
                    echo ">{$option}-{$optionprev}</option>";   
                }  
                echo "</select>"."&nbsp;(On or Before User cannot Calculate this Year)";    
            ?>
        </div>  
        {{ $errors->first('last_closing_financial_year', '<span class="alert-msg"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> :message</span>') }}
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn-flat success"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>save </button>
</form>
```

Please let me know if you something needed...

I tried many possible duplicate of this question but nothing worked.

I also tried this with no luck

```
$selected = "-- Select Year --";
foreach($years as $option)
{
     if($selected == $option){
      echo "<option selected='selected' value='$option'>$option</option>" ;
     }                                               
     else{
      echo "<option value='$option'>$option</option>" ;
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance.........

Comment: you just need to add `selected="selected"` to the option where it's value matches the value saved in the database.

Comment: @BrianGlaz thanks for your quick reply i already tried this with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this one works for you

In your controller:

```
$years = array();
for($i = 1980;$i<= 2050;$i++)
{
$before["$i"] = $i;
$nextyear["$i"] = $i + 1;   
$years["$i"] = $before["$i"] .(- $nextyear["$i"]);  //to show as 1980-1981 in your dropdown
}
```

In your view page

```
{{ Form::select('last_closing_financial_year', [null => '-- Select Year --'] + $years , Input::old('last_closing_financial_year', $setting->last_closing_financial_year)) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller:

```
// Create Select Values Array
$years = ['' => '-- Select a Year --'] + array_combine(range(1980, 2050), range(1980, 2050));

// Set default last closing year to last year
$defaultYear = Carbon::now()->subYear()->format('Y');
```

In your view:

```
{{ Form::select('last_closing_financial_year', $years, Input::old('last_closing_financial_year', $defaultYear)) }}
```

Comment: added the code in get edit function in controller & returned to view page, select statement in view page but it shows undefined variable years

Comment: Then you're not passing the variable to the view correctly somehow.  What does your View::make() statement look like?

Comment: got it but in my code i have mentioned that i need to show years as 1980-1981,1981-1982 and so on up to 2050-2051 in my drop down list how to achieve this.